# East up projection

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, rotate

I have tried to find a projection with east up, instead of the traditional north up, but haven’t been able to. Closest I can come is south up.

Basically, I want a Transverse Mercator using the zero meridian instead of the equator. 360 degrees high and 180 degrees wide. I do realize this creates massive distortions around the pacific. And it is only possible with math, since a real projection could not be 360 degrees high.

I feel like this should exist but I just can’t find it. If it doesn’t though; how would I go about defining it?

Comment: You could just rotate the map element in your layout by 90 degrees? Or is the desired output something other than a map?

Comment: I am writing a novel about the time when society was sun oriented and Orient was not just the eastern countries but the orientation of the world view. I think making an eastern oriented map will help the reader understand the world view and the increased distortion should also help to show that they didn’t have a perfect understanding of far away places. I don’t want to use a historical map because they don’t exist for this time period and the closest ones don’t depict the whole world. So making my own map is a necessity for my purpose.